# With VersionOne api, how to implement fetch of Story Names when implemented by javascript / html? query.v1 using Oauth2

Tags: javascript, json, versionone, oauth-2.0

I would like to begin consuming VersionOne api to use as building block for presenting custom HTML page view of Story Names (expand details on this later once I got the initial thing working).  I'd like to formulate this in HTML, javascript, JSON, OAUTH2 (no callback URL) implementation.  For this implementation the query.v1 endpoint is required and the usage/setup instructions for me aren't as clear/easy to use as the rest-1.v1.

I did "build"/download my personal client secret("v1_client_secrets.json).  Although I do not know what "using the scope query-api-1.0" from the documentation means or how it would get applied.   Api documentation I have been reading is here:  https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Sample_Code/Tour_of_query.v1

I am fine with the json data GET pattern below.

```
{
    "from": "Story",
    "select": [
        "Name"
    ]
}
```

Although there are examples of the JSON patterns, I can't seem to understand how to code it from start to finish.  Is there a starter template script (includes all html/javascript) based on my details, that someone could pass along? I am assuming jquery, angular, ajax would be incorporated in the retrieval/parse/read process.

FYI, I am new to this coding, especially consuming api, so hoping this all makes sense.

Comment: I'm just curious, why is query.v1 required?  BTW, oauth will be deprecated from VersionOne apps this year bit.ly/20BQgu7

Comment: I was not aware of deprecation of oauth in VersionOne.  I am just trying something to prove I can fetch data from api so I can present it to our web pages.  I imagine I can change the auth method as it changes in future, but right now oauth is the option I am aware of.

Comment: There is an JavaScript SDK that can be used to handle communicating with a VersionOne instance. `npm install v1sdk` can be used to install the package and can be found at https://www.npmjs.com/package/v1sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Javascript SDK you can communicate with a VersionOne instance. If you are using node you can install the package with `npm install v1sdk`. Otherwise the source code can be downloaded at https://github.com/versionone/VersionOne.SDK.JavaScript/ . An example of this.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import sdk, {jqueryConnector} from 'v1sdk';

const jqueryConnectedSdk = jqueryConnector($)(sdk);
const v1 = jqueryConnectedSdk('www14.v1host.com', 'v1sdktesting', 443, true)
    .withCreds('admin', 'admin'); // usage with username/password
//  .withAccessToken('your token'); // usage with access tokens

v1.create('Story', {estimate: 5, status: 'Not Started'})
    .then((story) => v1.update(story.oidToken, {estimate: 7}))
    .then(v1.query({
        from: 'Story',
        select: ['Estimate', 'Status'],
        where: {
            Status: 'Not Started'
        }
    }))
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.log);
```

This example shows creating a v1 connection, creating a story, updating that story, and then querying for that same story and selecting the Estimate and Status where the Status is 'Not Started'. This is an article that gives an example of displaying the backlog using the SDK http://walkerrandolphsmith.com/blog/v1sdk/. It also has an accompanying git repo you can look at mentioned in the article.